# Can you suggest any good books, online tutorials, etc, for developing with Bluetooth in JavaME?

Tags: java-me, mobile, bluetooth, wireless

I have limited experience with JavaME in the past.  I've worked in only basic UI of JavaME. I have not used any Bluetooth APIs before. My organization has assigned me to a team involved in  Bluetooth application development in JavaME.

Comment: Why doesn't your organization provide you with resources (or training) for this?

Comment: Your question is not exactly in the spirit of this website. Have you tried first to study the Bluetooth protocol? Maybe this would be the first point to start with, before any programming.

Comment: Lot of informations available on the [net](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=bluetooth+%2B+j2me&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1b15018c5645a505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some very old pdf: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ub.uib.no%2Felpub%2F2004%2Fh%2F413009%2Fmasteroppgave.pdf&ei=9j9lTeekPMSAOsTP7PEF&usg=AFQjCNEcCuR0vKiLZJTAL-4p1Jryr9Fgmg&sig2=zYAAkNTV7B3z1kW65G9q-Q

Some newer article: http://www.codeguru.com/java/article.php/c13147

Again something old, but maybe useful: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/27/bluetooth.html

Hope that helps a little.